# Cloud Firestore fetch multiple documents at once

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app that has `Users`, `Sports Teams` and `Articles`.

A `user` can follow any `sports team` and within that `sports team` some `users` will be contributors and post `articles` for the followers to see.

A million `users` could follow the same `sports team`, but only a few users, e.g. 10, would be contributors who can post `articles` about that particular `sports team`.

Reading up on Firestore, I may be inclined to structure my data in the following way:

**E.g. Structure:**

- `Users` *(Root Collection)*

  - User *(document)*

    - followingSportsTeamsIDs (map)
- `Sports Teams` *(Root Collection)*

  - Sport Team *(document)*

    - contributingUsersIDs (map)
    - `Posts` *(Subcollection)*

      - Post *(document)*

From my understanding if I want to perform a query to list all `Sports Teams` for those that I am a contributor for, I would simply do a fetch on `Sports Teams` `where('contributingUsersIDs.someUserID', '==', true)`.

**Question:**
How are you meant to do a simple query to retrieve the list of all the `Sports Teams` documents you as a particular user follow? In `Datastore` I'd simply do `ofy().load().keys(followingSportsTeamsIDsKeys).values()`.

Is the proper solution to simply do a fetch to retrieve all the `followingSportsTeamsIDs` a user has, then if say they follow a thousand different `Sports Teams` to simply do `db.collection("teams").document("someTeamID").getDocument` and make a request for each ID in a for loop on the client? That seems excessive? But maybe not because `Firestore` remains a persistent connection?

Or, how am I meant to restructure my data for `Firestore`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fetch multiple documents at once with Cloud Firestore (for now).

You're right, these type of joins can become pretty inefficient if you have to do the requests in a loop.  It's not as bad as if you were making a separate HTTP call for each one (as you said, they'll share a connection) but it's not great.

Instead you may want to duplicate some data. For example if you have a screen where the user can see each team they follow, maybe you only need the team name for each one on that screen.  In that case you could make users look like this:

```
{

  username: "whatever",
  teams: [
    {
      id: "team_1",
      name: "Team One"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is one of the tradeoffs you have to make when using a NoSQL database.  Optimize your data structure for how it will be used!

Comment: Unfortunately that structure isn't feasible, as I do have a screen where each user can see the teams they follow, but for each team it will also show them a preview of the latest article. If 100,000 people follow one team, then I'd have to do 100,000 writes each time a new article is posted to each users document. Unless there is another way? -- It seems the only solution going forward is to fetch each document separately in a loop, and hope Firebase makes good and will deliver the option in the future to fetch multiple documents at once? As you said, this is only (for now).

Comment: Having to give up the ability to retrieve entires in a database by their unique identifiers is not a tradeoff of using a NoSQL database. This is basic 101 stuff for any database, even the ones from the 1970s. The lack of this functionality is entirely about Google's decision making.